# How to reduce high cost of sort on execution plan

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

I have a very large query with three UNION ALL and it takes 30 minutes to execute.

Analyzing the execution plan I see that it has a high cost in SORT and Filter.

[image]

I tried to generate the showplan in XML but it's more than 2MB.

I put the complete query in OneDriver because it has 104364 characters

[link to the query](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag143-b7N6RbahA4Fx_wRXIQ9cs?e=HmuDpU)

Could someone help me to improve the execution time of the query?

Thanks.